# Value is not passed through the React Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I'm trying to re-write my app using React Context API but have faced with the next issue - the value I'd like to pass through Provider to Consumer is not passed.

**Initial State:**

```
let initialState = {
    ve: 'randomValue'
};

export default initialState;
```

**Provider:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MyContext from './myContext';

import initialState from './initialState';

class MyProvider extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
}

render() {
    return(
        <MyContext.Provider value={{
            state: this.state,
        }}>
            {this.props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
    }
};

export default MyProvider;
```

**Consumer:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

import MyContext from './Context/myContext';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {context => (
          <View>
            <Text>
              {context}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors but no Context value as well.

Comment: Is App component rendered as a child of MyProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Provider` component somewhere above the `MyContext.Consumer` component as well.

**Example**

```js
const initialState = {
  ve: "randomValue"
};
const MyContext = React.createContext();

class MyProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          {context => <div>{JSON.stringify(context)}</div>}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```