# NextJS React Context API not updating value when using useState()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I have a React Context API in use in my NextJS web app.
I'd like to persist a value throughout the web app.  I know I can use the `Consumer` tag inside the `Provider` tag to update the value.

Like so:

```
<ProfileContext.Provider>
    <ProfileContext.Consumer>{... some logic ...}</ProfileContext.Consumer>
</ProfileContext.Provider>
```

But I'd like to use the `useContext()` call to update a value by passing in a State object.

#### user_profile.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react'

const ProfileContext = createContext()

export function ProfileProvider({ children }) {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState("default value")

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ profile, setProfile }}>
      {children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useProfileContext = () => {
  return useContext(ProfileContext)
}
```

The issue is the value I assign using `setProfile(...)` does not retain value when I navigate to another page.

#### user_account.js

```
...
export default function UserAccount() {
  const profileContext = useProfileContext()

  profileContext.setProfile("SOME TEXT PROFILE VALUE")
  console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT: ", profileContext.profile)  // This will show previously set value 

  return (...)
}
```

#### _app.js

```
export default function App(pageProps) {
  return (
    <ProfileProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ProfileProvider>
  )
}
```

When I navigate to some other page, the state will not have changed and will return null or the default value.

#### some_other_page.js

```
...
export default function Home() {
  const profileContext = useProfileContext()
  console.log(profileContext.profile)  // "default value" 

  return (...)
}
```

My main guide was https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/01/using-react-context-for-state-management-in-next.js

Most other examples I've read use the `Provier-Consumer` tags to access and change the Context value.

- [Value is not passed through the React Context API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54855525/value-is-not-passed-through-the-react-context-api)

Comment: Could you provide a working example on live editor like codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist the value through page navigation or refreshes, you'll likely need to store the profile value in something that's persisted and load the value from the data store to the context. You can use something like a db or possibly local storage. On app load, you'll make the API call to retrieve these values and store it in your context.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `profileContext.setProfile` call into useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    profileContext.setProfile("SOME TEXT PROFILE VALUE")
  }, [profileContext]);
```

[Cannot update a component while rendering a different component warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning)